# highcharts piechart - small number of colors

Tags: r, highcharts, pie-chart, shiny

I'm using highcharts (piecharts) within a Shiny app and it seems like the default number of different colors are pretty small (I think it's 6 colors).Any idea how to increase it X2?

Comment: check `?palette` as starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your colors in an array like this

```
colors: ['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', 
'#1aadce', '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a']
```

If you have problems you can check highcharts [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors)